# CPU High Load because of search engines mass crawling

Tags: mysql, server, web-crawler, search-engine, cpanel

I have a server containing many web sites,
And when some sites have huge updates, Search engines like :

Bing (Specially), Yandex, Yahoo

Come to the server using many IP addresses and they don't attention to the CPU load and MySQL queries and try to fetch web pages in the same time,

So how can I limit them for whole the server

Currently I blocked these search engine IPs
Thank you

Comment: Search engines are the life blood of most websites, blocking them is counter productive. If their crawling is causing performance issues the you need to investigate why your websites can't cope with this load, improve the code and sql queries to make them more efficient, and if that isn't enough, get more powerful servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a robots.txt so the search engine will read it and know that is not allowed to index (crawl) whatever you specify on it.

For bing, for instance, here is a guide: https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-create-a-robots-txt-file-cb7c31ec